# Error in ODataMetadata.js SAP Hana Cloud

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana

In the app that I am creating I have a home view when the createCaseButton is clicked the createCase view is opened, but when I click to open this view I am getting the following error please see attached image. I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this. Any help would be amazing

[Errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LQ5I.jpg)

Here is my code:

CreateCase controller:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.MessageBox");
sap.ui.controller("casemanagement.CreateCase", {

onInit: function() {
    var sOrigin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname
    + (window.location.port ? ":" + window.location.port : "");
    var caseTrackerOdataServiceUrl = sOrigin + "/CaseTracker/#/case.svc";

    var odataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(caseTrackerOdataServiceUrl);
    odataModel.setCountSupported(false);
    this.getView().setModel(odataModel);

},

AddCase : function(aCaseType,aReason,aDateOpened,aEmployee,aDescription,aComment,aAttachment){

    if(aCaseType != "" && aReason != "" && aDateOpened != "" && aEmployee != "" && aDescription != "" && aComment != "")        
    {       
    var Cases = {};

    Cases.caseTypeId = aCaseType;
    Cases.reasonId = aReason;
    Cases.dateOpened = aDateOpened;
    Cases.employeeId = aEmployee;
    Cases.description = aDescription;
    Cases.comments = aComment;
    Cases.stageId = "open"

    this.getView().getModel().create("/CreateCase", Cases, null, this.successMsg, this.errorMsg);

    Cases = {};

    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this.router.navTo("CreateCasePage");
    }
    else
    {
        sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Please fill in all fields before submitting")
    }   
},

successMsg : function() {
    sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Case has been successfully created");
},

errorMsg : function() {
    sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Error occured when creating the case");
},
```

CreateCase View:

```
sap.ui.jsview("casemanagement.CreateCase", {

/** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
* In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
* @memberOf casemanagement.CreateCase.CreateCase
*/ 
getControllerName : function() {
    return "casemanagement.CreateCase";
},

/** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
* Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away. 
* @memberOf casemanagement.CreateCase.CreateCase
*/ 
createContent : function(oController) {                     

    var aPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({width:"810px"});

    aPanel.setTitle(new sap.ui.core.Title({text:"Create New Case"}));

    var aMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed:true, width:"610px",columns:8});
    aMatrix.setWidths("110px","100px","100px","300px");
    var bMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed:true,width:"610px", columns:2});
    aMatrix.setWidths("110px","500px");

    //first row of fields
    var caseTypeLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Case Type"});
    var caseTypeInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"100%", id:"caseTypeId", value:''});
    caseTypeLabel.setLabelFor(caseTypeInput);

    aMatrix.createRow(caseTypeLabel,caseTypeInput);

    //second row        
    var reasonLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Reason"});
    var reasonInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"100%", id:"reasonId", value:''});
    reasonLabel.setLabelFor(reasonInput);

    aMatrix.createRow(reasonLabel,reasonInput);

    //third row
    var dateOpenedLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Date Opened"});
    var dateOpenedInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({widht:"100%", id: "dateOpenedId", value:''});
    dateOpenedLabel.setLabelFor(dateOpenedInput);

    aMatrix.createRow(dateOpenedLabel,dateOpenedInput)

    //fourth row

    var employeeLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Employee"});
    var employeeIDInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"100%", id:"employeeId",value:''});
    var employeeNameInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"100%"});

    aMatrix.createRow(employeeLabel,employeeIDInput,employeeNameInput);

    //fifth row

    var descriptionLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Description"});
    var descriptionInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"100%",id:"descriptionId",value:''});
    descriptionLabel.setLabelFor(descriptionInput);

    aMatrix.createRow(descriptionLabel,descriptionInput)

    aPanel.addContent(aMatrix);     

    var bPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({width:"810px"});

    bPanel.setTitle(new sap.ui.core.Title({text:"Actions"}));

    bPanel.setCollapsed(false);

    var cMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed:true,width:"810px",columns:2});
    cMatrix.setWidths("110px","700px");

    var attachmentLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Attachments"});
    var addAttachmentButton = new sap.ui.commons.FileUploader({
    uploadUrl : "../../../../../upload",
    name: "attachmentUploader",           
    uploadOnChange: true
    });

    var commentsLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Comments"});
    var commentsInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({width:"95%",id:"commentsId",value:''});
    var submitButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"createCaseButtonId",text:"Submit", press : function(){oController.AddCase(
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("caseTypeId").getValue(), 
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("reasonId").getValue(),
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("dateOpenedId").getValue(),
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("employeeId").getValue(),
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("descriptionId").getValue(),
                                                sap.ui.getCore().getControl("commentsId").getValue()

        )}
    });

    cMatrix.createRow(attachmentLabel,addAttachmentButton);
    cMatrix.createRow(commentsLabel,commentsInput);
    cMatrix.createRow(submitButton);

    bPanel.addContent(cMatrix);

    var container = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout({
        content: [aPanel,bPanel]
    });

    return container;
},

});
```

Home controller:

```
sap.ui.controller("casemanagement.Home", {

/**
 * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if
 * available) are already created. Can be used to modify the View before it
 * is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time
 * initialization.
 * 
 * @memberOf casemanagement.Home.Home
 */
//  onInit : function() {
//      
//  },

loadCreateCase : function() {
    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this.router.navTo("CreateCasePage");
},

loadSearchCase : function() {
    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this.router.navTo("SearchCasePage");
}
```

Home view:

```
sap.ui.jsview("casemanagement.Home", {

/** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
* In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
* @memberOf casemanagement.Home.Home
*/ 
getControllerName : function() {
    return "casemanagement.Home";
},

/** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
* Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away. 
* @memberOf casemanagement.Home.Home
*/ 
createContent : function(oController) {                         

    var oPanelButtons = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({width:"600px",position:"center"});

    oPanelButtons.setTitle(new sap.ui.core.Title({text:"Case Management"}));

    var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed: true, width:"400px",columns:4, position:"center"});
    oMatrix.setWidths("100px","100px","100px","100px");

    var createCaseButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:'createId',text:"Create Case",press : function(){oController.loadCreateCase()}});
    var searchButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"Search Cases",press : function(){oController.loadSearchCase()}});
    var analyticsButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:'analyticsId',text:"Case Analytics"});
    var helpButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:'helpId',text:"Help"});

    oMatrix.createRow(createCaseButton,searchButton,analyticsButton,helpButton);

    oPanelButtons.addContent(oMatrix);

    var oPanelTable = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({width:"600px",position:"center"});  

    var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
        inset: true,
        headerText: "Open Cases Pending Your Action",
        headerDesign : sap.m.ListHeaderDesign.Standard,
        mode: sap.m.ListMode.None,
        includeItemInSelection: true
        });

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column({
        inset : true,
        header: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Case#"}),
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column({
        inset : true,
        header: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Submitted By"}),
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column({
        inset : true,
        header: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Created On"}),
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column({
        inset : true,
        header: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Case Type"}),
    }));

    oPanelTable.addContent(oTable);

    var container = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout({
        id: "container",
        content:[oPanelButtons,oPanelTable]
    });

    return container;
},

});
```

Comment: If the error-message is right, then the returned metadata document on the service has errors in it. Please check the network-tab ob your browser's development tools for the URL ending in "$metadata and" check its contents.

Comment: The error message is "<u>/CaseTracker/CreateCasePage/case.svc/$metadata</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>" not too sure why though

Comment: An OData v2 Service must (to be used with UI5) always have a metadata document under [ServiceRoot]/$metadata. Without that XML file the OData model does not know enough about the service to do anything meaningful. See http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#ServiceMetadataDocument